# Select from two tables and show everything in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4.2

I want to show on the page data from two tables but with a little condition and I can't figured it out how to make it in Laravel 4.

So I have table `categories` and table `products`. Currently I show all categories on the page and there is no problem. The problem is now there will have products without category and I want to loop them also on the page.

When admin create product he choose category but if doesn't choose any it will save `1` default in database `products` column `single_product`.

This is Product model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Categories', 'category_id');
}
```

And Categories model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Product', 'category_id');
} 

public function lowestProduct() {
    return $this->products()->selectRaw('*, max(price) as aggregate')
    ->groupBy('products.product_id')->orderBy('aggregate');
}
```

And this is the view

```
    <div class="col-xs-8 text-left" style="margin-top: 9px">
        @if($category['no_category'] == 0)
            Price: <strong>{{ $category->products()->min('price') }} $</strong>                         
        @else
            Price from: <strong>{{ $category->products()->min('price') }} $</strong> 
         @endif
    </div>
```

How to select `single` column from `products` table and show them on the page along with categories name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then there is no category. Avoid your category class and just fetch directly from the product class. Create a function like:

```
public function singleItems()
{
   return $this->where("single_product", 1)->get();

}
```

Then you foreach the result out. Please check this for further information:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections

I know above is for another version of laravel than yours, but I think it should work. Else tell me, then I will look further.

Comment: In which file I should put this .. in Product model? And how to foreach them then?

Comment: You should foreach them in your view file or routes file. You can do the exact same with the categories.

Comment: Thank's! I think I got it. I;ve put it in the home controller + second loop in my view..